# How to iterate link inside unknown total page number?

Tags: python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I want to get all the application link inside every pages.But the problem is the total page inside each category is not same.
I have this code:

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url ='http://www.brothersoft.com/windows/mp3_audio/'
pageUrl = urllib.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(pageUrl)

for a in soup.select('div.coLeft.cate.mBottom dd a[href]'):
        print 'http://www.brothersoft.com'+a['href'].encode('utf-8','repalce')
        suburl = 'http://www.brothersoft.com'+a['href'].encode('utf-8','repalce')

        for page in range(1,27+1):
                content = urllib.urlopen(suburl+'{}.html'.format(page))
                soup = BeautifulSoup(content)
                for a in soup.select('div.freeText dl a[href]'):
                        print 'http://www.brothersoft.com'+a['href'].encode('utf-8','repalce')
```

But I only get link of application for 27 pages in each category.
What if the other category do not have 27 pages or more than 27 pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract number of programs and devide it by 20. For example, if you open URL - `http://www.brothersoft.com/windows/photo_image/font_tools/2.html` then:

```
import re
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

tmp = re.compile("1-(..)")
url ='http://www.brothersoft.com/windows/photo_image/font_tools/2.html'
pageUrl = urllib.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(pageUrl)
pages = soup.find("div", {"class":"freemenu coLeft Menubox"})
page = pages.text
print int(re.search(r'of ([\d]+) ', page).group(1)) / 20 + 1
```

Output will be:

```
18
```

For http://www.brothersoft.com/windows/photo_image/cad_software/6.html URL output will be `108`.

So you need to open some page where you can find how many pages. Scrap that number, and then you can run your loop.It could be something like this:

```
import re
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

tmp = re.compile("1-(..)")
url ='http://www.brothersoft.com/windows/photo_image/'
pageUrl = urllib.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(pageUrl)

for a in soup.select('div.coLeft.cate.mBottom dd a[href]'):
        suburl = 'http://www.brothersoft.com'+a['href'].encode('utf-8','repalce')
        print suburl

        content = urllib.urlopen(suburl+'2.html')
        soup1 = BeautifulSoup(content)
        pages = soup1.find("div", {"class":"freemenu coLeft Menubox"})
        page = pages.text
        allPages =  int(re.search(r'of ([\d]+) ', page).group(1)) / 20 + 1
        print allPages
        for page in range(1, allPages+1):
                content = urllib.urlopen(suburl+'{}.html'.format(page))
                soup = BeautifulSoup(content)
                for a in soup.select('div.freeText dl a[href]'):
                        print 'http://www.brothersoft.com'+a['href'].encode('utf-8','repalce')
```

Comment: I just found out that the first page is not printed.